# RDP file transfer via command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, rdp

I'm making some automated deployment software leveraging Chef and Python for my internship. Unfortunately, the environment is completely airgapped aside from me being able to initialize and RDP connection from a client machine to one of the server.

Being unfamiliar with Windows, I am wondering if it's possible to do something similar to scp within windows to RDP a file from one machine to another via `powershell` or equivalent. Ideally I want to execute something like `cli-rdp 68.98.xx.xxx -x admin -p pass c:\file_name c:\desktop\file_name` to transfer a local file to the remote machine. I'm building a winform wrapper to handle this execution and this would make it much easier if something was built in.

Comment: Are the endpoints VMs, and if so, which hypervisor is being used?

Comment: Can you use SSH secure connections?  If so, use FileZilla or WinSCP on the Windows box.  Also I believe the PuTTY suite comes with command-line versions of secure copy.  You will want to generate a key and copy it to the other server so it can be scripted.  i.e., so it will not ask for a password.